# Java InvalidKeyException Symmetric Key

Tags: java, encryption

so I am retrieve from file the private key and symmetric key. Now I am trying to decrypt the symmetric key with the private key so I can encrypt other data. The problem is that I'm getting InvalidKeyException but I'm not sure why. Any suggestions?

The error:
java.security.InvalidKeyException: No installed provider supports this key: javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec

It shows up in line : cipher2.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, sym);

```
        ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(keyPath));
        byte[] symmetric = (byte[]) input.readObject();
        input.close();
        ObjectInputStream input2 = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("private.key"));
        PrivateKey pk = (PrivateKey) input2.readObject();
        input2.close();
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, pk);
        symmetric = cipher.doFinal(symmetric);
        SecretKey sym = new SecretKeySpec(symmetric,0,symmetric.length,"AES");
        Cipher cipher2 = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
        cipher2.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, sym);
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
        oos.writeObject(card);
        oos.flush();
        byte [] data = bos.toByteArray();
        byte[] encryptedCard = cipher2.doFinal(data);
```

Symmetric Key Generation

```
KeyGenerator key = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        key.init(256);
        SecretKey secretKey = key.generateKey();
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pk);
        byte[] symmetric = cipher.doFinal(secretKey.getEncoded());
```

Comment: On which line does this error occur? Whats the exact error-message?

Comment: I updated the description! Thank you!

Comment: Only write `AES` instead of `AES-256` in `SecretKey sym = new SecretKeySpec(symmetric,0,symmetric.length,"AES-256");`

Comment: Same error, nothing changes

Comment: So I need to change .getInstance("RSA") with one of those?

Comment: I used just RSA in other examples and it worked fine. Why now should I change it? Thank you!

Comment: Just writing `RSA` seems to be valid as well. I guess you don't need to change it then.

Comment: I updated the description with symmetric key generation code I used

Comment: It doesn't make sense to use RSA with a symmetric key, which is what you are trying to do. A symmetric key goes with a symmetric algorithm like AES.

Comment: I have to use RSA in Cipher.getInstance, it was a requirement in the assignment